# how can i create gulp task to run a script shell?

Tags: jenkins, gulp

I have this script shell and i want to create task gulp to execute it.

```
for tag in `git tag -l | sort -V |head -n -4`
    do
        echo $tag
        if [ -n "$(echo $tag | grep -P "(^v.*-*)")" ] then
            echo VERSION=$(echo $tag | grep -P "(^v.*-*)")
            git tag -d $(echo $tag | grep -P "(^v.*-*)")
            git push origin :$tag        
        fi
    done
```

I'm using those plugins in my gulpfile :

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    shell = require('gulp-shell'),
    pckg = require('./package.json'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
```

is there any solution?

Comment: https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell

Comment: it looks like you've got gulp-shell. what have you tried? maybe start with "ls" or something simpler, see if that works, and add functionality from there?